# WebSocket connection failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am following a tutorial to create a WebRTC demo project, but I am unable to create a WebSocket connection even when following the same steps.

The tutorial's project is running on port 8080 and it mentioned "ws://localhost:9090", and mine on port 8081. I copied the URL "ws://localhost:9090" from their because I didn't know the significance of 9090, and I received this error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed: Error in
> connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I changed local host to 8081 as well but then I am getting hand shake error.

My server is Node.js.

Comment: This could be related to CORS, for example I could not connect to websocket server in spring boot until I add `.setAllowedOrigins("*")`, when connecting from a differnt IP/Port.

Answer (score 45):

Chrome doesn't allow unsecure websocket (ws) connections to localhost (only wss, so you should setup a TLS certificate for your local web/websocket server).
However the same should work fine with Firefox.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `ws://yourIp:9090/`, where yourIP is like `192.168.?.?`.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is a generic websocket issue.

Change the url to a dynamic name using the built-in `location.host` variable and change the protocol to secure websocket `wss` if you have set-up the TLS:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://" + location.host + "/")
```

Answer (score 4):

Usually WebRTC requires a secure connection (that is https).
The error you have got is due to TLS/SSL certificates occupied, may be they are not properly configured in your project. 
Provide a valid TLS/SSL certificate and also configure it correctly in project, then it will work without the above error.

Answer (score 4):

also you could easily change the mappings of **IP addresses** to host names,
on windows go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and uncomment this line

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

save and restart.

Answer (score 3):

try to change the port to 8080

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/chat')
```

Comment: What is the significance of `chat` here? Wouldn't that be invalid port?

Comment: it's the path in the wesockets server server url, e.g. /chat for your chat messages, /matches for your tinder matches, etc. probably for some scaling concerns

Answer (score 3):

Port 9090 is used by reactotron. Probably you are using it in your project and your app cannot connect with reactotron because it is closed. Just open reactotron and the error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot to start websocket server, check it again, with configuration in my project, run:

`php artisan websocket:init`